# Admob ads won't show

Tags: swift, admob

Hey guys I've a big problem.

I recently released my app (game) to the App Store.

I used admob banners and interstitials which now don't show in my app.

Here's my code for the banners and interstitials in my gameviewcontroller.

thats for the banners

```
 func loadAd(){
    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

    self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
    let request = GADRequest()

    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.adUnitID = "myCodeXXXXXXXXXX"
    bannerView.load(request)

    bannerView.center = CGPoint(x: 335.5, y: 350)
}
```

and this for the interstitials

```
func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
    let requestInter = GADRequest()
    let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "myCodeXXXXXXXXX")

    interstitial.delegate = self

    interstitial.load(requestInter)

    return interstitial
}
```

the ads always get shown on the simulator as test ads. But on a real device nothing gets shown.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have app (vpn, proxy , ..etc) that disable ads in apps.

Comment: have you configure your app id with GoogleAds in appdelegate ?

Comment: if you have configure correct then after 2 or 3 hour it will display. Or you can use **request.testdevices = [kGADSimulatorID]** for testing

Comment: Yes the ads will show up on the simulator but not on a real device. I haven't configured anything in the app delegate. I did everything in the GamviewController.